# Css zoom animation not working without Firefox

Tags: css

My code working on Firefox, The problem is in other browsers not working the animation. I check those links But not find any solution. (I'm working on WordPress)
1.[CSS Animation Not working in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976585/css-animation-not-working-in-all-browsers)
2.[CSS Animation not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588628/css-animation-not-working-in-chrome)
3.[FadeInUp css animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337404/fadeinup-css-animation-not-working)
4.[CSS flipping animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567216/css-flipping-animation-not-working)
And more

My Code

```
@keyframes zoom {
  0%{
    background-size: auto 100%;
  }
  25%{
    background-size: auto 105%;
  }
  50%{
    background-size: auto 110%;
  }
  75%{
    background-size: auto 115%;
  }
  100%{
    background-size: auto 120%;
  }
}

.banner {
  background-image: url("../img/hero.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: 15000ms linear 0s alternate none 1 running zoom;
  -moz-animation: 15000ms linear 0s alternate none 1 running zoom;
  -ms-animation: 15000ms linear 0s alternate none 1 running zoom;
  -o-animation: 15000ms linear 0s alternate none 1 running zoom;
  animation: 15000ms linear 0s alternate none 1 running zoom;
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;

  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

I also try

```
@keyframes zoom {
    from {
      background-size: auto 100%;

    }
    to {
      background-size: auto 120%;
    }
  }

  .banner {
    background-image: url("../img/hero.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: zoom 12s 1 linear;
       -moz-animation: zoom 12s 1 linear;
        -ms-animation: zoom 12s 1 linear;
         -o-animation: zoom 12s 1 linear;
            animation: zoom 12s 1 linear;
    background-size: auto 100%;
  }
```

Those codes only working on Firefox.

Comment: there is also a webkit version of keyframes e.g: @-webkit-keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also use

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
from {
  background-size: auto 100%;

}
to {
  background-size: auto 120%;
 }
}
```